# pod init cause RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version

Tags: ios, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

When I run `pod init`, I got the following error.

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:227:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:112:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: any update about that?

Answer (score 112):

I've got very similar error: `RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56).`

It turns out the cocopapods doesn't know how to work with Xcode 14 project version properly and it complains instead.

To solve the issue, open Xcode project on the right side utility panel and change the project version to `Xcode 13.0 - compatible` and you are good to go.

[image: Changing Xcode version to Xcode 13.0 to fix cocoapods issue about object version 56]

Comment: This worked for me, just updated XCode yesterday and creating a new project it's crashing - not good

Comment: This seems to be the only thing that works. Thank you

Comment: The only useful answer I found on the entire internet. Thanks mate.

Comment: Did not work for me. I had to do 
`sudo gem update xcodeproj`
and then 
`pod init`

Answer (score 92):

After investigation, I found I need to run

```
sudo gem update xcodeproj
```

Then run

```
pod init
```

Comment: this solution not work for me.

Comment: Same. Updated `xcodeproj`, but still doesn't work. 

P.S. There is a temporary workaround - set `objectVersion` to 55 in `project.pbxproj`. Keep in mind, that it will be updated to 56 by Xcode if anything changes in the project.

Comment: update Xcode project and then pod install worked for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: Works for me after install cocoapods (1.11.3) and ffi (1.15.5) on MacOS 12.6 (M1).

Answer (score 15):

I initially tried this: `sudo gem update xcodeproj`

If it did not work (that was my case):

`brew uninstall cocoapods`

then

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

after that

`pod init`

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because podfile not created correctly.

I have created podfile as **touch podfile** instead of **touch Podfile**
After researching log found that Podfile should start with capital.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install --user-install cocoapods
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
and restart terminal
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then go to your project directory and write `pod init`.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The real problem is the Xcode version does not match up with your cocoapods version. The command could be pod init or pod install, you'll face with the same error as the original question shared.

## Solutions

I've faced this issue multiple times, so I'll be sharing all the different scenarios that I've faced in the past couple of years.

### First

Open the .xcodeproj. Navigate to **Project Navigator > Click the root project, check the right-hand panel > Find Identity and type**.

Over there, change the project format to any version lower than the latest version.

### Second

You need to first run the:

```
gem update xcodeproj
```

If the update operation does not fix your problem, then you have to run:

```
gem uninstall xcodeproj
```

and then:

```
gem install xcodeproj
```

### Third

I've another Mac machine that I didn't update anything on the terminal for a long time. In that machine, the solution was different than the solutions listed above. I've tried all of them but didn't work for me. My only solution was the uninstall and reinstall the cocoapods itself. First run:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then run:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I hope this answer will collect all the possible solutions for the case. If you've experienced an alternative scenario please let me know in the comments below.